# Set language of TYPO3 StandaloneView in CommandController

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using the TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView in a CommandController to send emails to my fe_user.

The part where im building the template looks like this:

```
    /* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView $emailView */
    $emailView = $this->objectManager->get( 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView' );

    // pass extension name to standaloneView for translations
    $extensionName = $this->request->getControllerExtensionName();
    $emailView->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName( $extensionName );

    $extensionPath           = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath( 'my_extension' );
    $templatePathAndFilename = $extensionPath . 'Resources/Private/Templates/Email/' . $templateFile . '.html';
    $emailView->setLayoutRootPath( $extensionPath . 'Resources/Private/Layouts/Email/' );
    //$emailView->setPartialRootPath($ressourcePath . 'Partials/');

    $emailView->setTemplatePathAndFilename( $templatePathAndFilename );

    return $emailView->render();
```

Nothing special i think.

In the html-Template i'm using the normal translate ViewHelper of Fluid:

```
<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:mail.text" />
```

This all works well in the standard language, but i've no idea how i can tell the View/CommandController **which language to use**.

I'm not quite sure if this is a StandaloneView or a CommandController problem...

**Edit:**

The posted snippet is called from the CommandController (Scheduler) - so there is no current frontend user (we are in backend environment). I get the user from a repository so i've to save the selected language in there. But then i've to set the language for the StandaloneView

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can set the language in a CommandController by doing this:

```
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->uc['lang'] = 'de';
```

The problem is that the LocalizationUtility creates a cache for the extension after it's been called once to ::translate() something. There is no available function to reset that cache, but you can add this little utility function in your extension to enable you to do just that:

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Utility;

class LocalizationUtility extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility
{
   public static function resetExtensionLangCache($extensionName){
       unset(static::$LOCAL_LANG[$extensionName]);
   }
}
```

If you have the case where you have to switch the full language context in your CommandController you can now call this right after switching the language for the BE_USER:

```
\Vendor\Extension\Utility\LocalizationUtility::resetExtensionLangCache('<extensionname>');
```

This will reset the cache and LocalizationUtility will have to initialize its entry for your extension until you switch and call it again.

Answer (score 1):

To control the language used in a Fluid StandaloneView from the backend context, just set the language as shown below (I set the language to german).

```
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->uc['lang'] = 'de';
```

This should be set before you call the `$emailView->render()` method.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works when you also set the extension name with `$view->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName()` and then only use the key in your `f:translate` calls (but not the path to the whole file), otherwise you'll still get the default language labels.

Comment: ... and it only works if you send one email. As soon as you send multiple emails with each having its own language, it won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you want to send an email in language currently used by user, in that case, you should create language config for the additional languages, like [described in TYPO3 docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/BasicSetupOfALocalizedWebsite/TyposcriptConfiguration/Index.html).

When configured properly and non-default language is used, all your views (also these standalone) will be translated to the *current* language.

AFAUK, there's no way to force translate VH to use some language ie. by giving it's uid.

Comment: I use the CommandController / Scheduler so there is no _current_ user. TYPO3 does not have a setting for the chosen language of fe_users so i've to save this on my own.

Comment: Same issue here. Sending emails from BE and using Fluid. Having a hard time to translate the mails based upon some FE records language. Having a way to force the translate VH into a specific language would be great.